Flutter DeepLink work on android but not in iOS
I have a trouble with deep links on iOS Flutter. I join at team that need the deep links on ios and they only worked on android. I have 3 classes:
The flutter deeplink bloc
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:fertil_wallet/models/deep_link_route.dart';
import 'package:fertil_wallet/pages/pagar/pago_con_link/pago_con_link.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
part 'deeplink_event.dart';
part 'deeplink_state.dart';

class DeeplinkBloc extends Bloc<DeeplinkEvent, DeeplinkState> {
  //Event Channel creation
  static const streamObj = const EventChannel('wallet/events');

  final String webDomain;
  final TargetPlatform _targetPlatform;

  //Method channel creation
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('wallet/channel');

  DeeplinkBloc(this.webDomain, this._targetPlatform)
      : super(DeeplinkState(null, false)) {
    startUri();
    streamObj.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((d) => _onRedirected(d));

    on<LinkRecieved>((event, emit) => emit(DeeplinkState(event.route, false)));
    on<OnboardingCompletedExternally>(
        (event, emit) => emit(DeeplinkState(null, true)));
  }

  _onRedirected(String uri) {
    // Here can be any uri analysis, checking tokens etc, if it’s necessary
    // Throw deep link URI into the BloC's stream

    var uriSections = uri.split("/");
    var i = uriSections.indexOf(webDomain);
    if (i == -1) return; //no es un link de el dominio de la app
    uriSections = uriSections.sublist(i + 1, uriSections.length);
    if (uriSections[0] != "app") return;

    DeepLinkRoute? route;
    switch (uriSections[1]) {
      case "lc":
        route = DeepLinkRoute(
          route: PagoConLinkPage.route,
          arguments: uriSections.length >= 2 ? uriSections[2] : "",
        );
        this.add(LinkRecieved(route));
        return;
      case "ob":
        this.add(OnboardingCompletedExternally());
        return;
      case "recover_password":
      case "account_activation":
        launchUrlString(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        return;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  Future<void> startUri() async {
    try {
      //if (_targetPlatform != TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      var url = await platform.invokeMethod('nani');

      _onRedirected(url);

      // return url;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return "Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'." as Future;
    } catch (e) {
      return "Failed to Invoke: '$e'." as Future;
    }
  }
}

after that I have the android native class:
package com.ayj.wallet

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
// import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.EventSink

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Context


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver


class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity () {

    private val CHANNEL = "wallet/channel"
    private val EVENTS = "wallet/events"
    private var startString: String? = null
    private var linksReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null



    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        val intent2 = getIntent()
        startString = intent2.data?.toString()
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "nani") {
                if (startString != null) {
                    result.success(startString)
                }
            }
        }
        EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, EVENTS).setStreamHandler(
            object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
                override fun onListen(args: Any?, events: EventSink) {
                    linksReceiver = createChangeReceiver(events)
                }

                override fun onCancel(args: Any?) {
                    linksReceiver = null
                }
            }
        )
    }

  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent)
      if (intent.action === Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
          linksReceiver?.onReceive(this.applicationContext, intent)
      }
  }

  fun createChangeReceiver(events: EventSink): BroadcastReceiver? {
      return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
          override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) { // NOTE: assuming intent.getAction() is Intent.ACTION_VIEW
              val dataString = intent.dataString ?:
              events.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Link unavailable", null)
              events.success(dataString)
          }
      }
  }
}

and the last it's a appdelegate class that I put the code inside:
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    private let CHANNEL = "wallet/channel"
    private let EVENTS = "wallet/events"
    private var startString: String?

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        let flutterViewController: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController

        let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: CHANNEL, binaryMessenger: flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler { [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) in
            if call.method == "nani" {
                if let startString = self?.startString {
                    result(startString)
                }
            }
        }

        let eventChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: EVENTS, binaryMessenger: flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
        eventChannel.setStreamHandler(StreamHandler())

        // Handling deep link if the app is opened via a deep link
        if let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL {
            processDeepLink(url)
        }

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        processDeepLink(url)
        return true
    }

    private func processDeepLink(_ url: URL) {
        startString = url.absoluteString
        if let flutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
            let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: CHANNEL, binaryMessenger: flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
            methodChannel.invokeMethod("nani", arguments: nil) { (result) in
                print("Deep link processed: \(String(describing: result))")
            }
        }
    }
}

class StreamHandler: NSObject, FlutterStreamHandler {
    var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?

    func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
        eventSink = events
        return nil
    }

    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        eventSink = nil
        return nil
    }
}



The problem is: iOS app not redirect me to a view, appdelegate can't get the deeplink and sent of flutter
When I debug the lines on bloc go well but on method _onRedirect iOS never entry.
If I send a deeplink on out of the app always sent me to home and can't redirect, when I try the same on android work well.
I have all configurations (apple-app-site-association, associated domains, EnableFlutterLink on Yes)

make sure you have defined you DeepLink Path in info.plist (ios\Runner\Info.plist) file same as in AndroidManifest.xml (android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml)

I think go_router is the best tool for implementing deeplinks in flutter, I've used it myself and it worked well on Android and IOS.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
